# Android resize ImageView with gravity=Left

Tags: android, image, layout, resize, gravity

I've an imageview with an icon on background, instead of generating all diferent sizes of icons for diferent sizes of screen i'm using only a big one and resizing it to fit the size I want.

If I set the layout_height to any value android automatically resize the width to keep aspect ratio (what is good) but the placeholder keeps the original width and the new resized icon is centered in the space it was supposed to fit

To demonstrate the situation i took this print

[image]

both left and right icons have the same dimension in original file

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/leftThumb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_left_thumb" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rightThumb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_right_thumb" />
```

setting only the imageview height and is it possible to make it resizes keeping gravity on left? (as in the print bellow)

[image]

Comment: I could not understand, what do you need. Can you post an expected view?

Comment: I want the image get resized and aligned to the edge... like in the second print on the right side... but when i resize they get aligned to the center (center of original size) then this weird gap appears in the image (like the left side)

Comment: Seems like your drawable image has unnecessary padding on left and right. That's why it is not controllable. You can get a new or remove padding of drawable by cropping image.Then you can get desired output.

Comment: there ihere is no padding in my image... this gap appears because when android resize the height it adjusts the width of the rendered image but IT KEEPS THE ORIGINAL WIDTH SIZE... so the image is centered in the horizontal space it would fit if was full sized...

i believe there isn't any way to change this so i need to solve it by other way

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple.

**Set your parent layout height as desired** and **its children height to "match_parent"**
You can use "**dimen.xml**" files to control different sized screen dimensions, for now i have put a static value of "64dp" **android:layout_height="64dp"**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/leftThumb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_left_thumb" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rightThumb"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_right_thumb" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it doens't work, the result is the same as if I set the height on the imageview...
the icons get resized, but they dont align to the edges, they stay in the center keeping the wrong margin

Comment: 1st of all I think there is an issue with sizes of your icon as your screenshots suggest there is padding(transperent) in your image itself.
2nd do not put height on imageview put height on it's parent thats the rightway to do
3rd do not use foregroundGravity if you imageView image/src does not have any transparent paddings it will itself adjust
4th use scaleType in imageview and tell me how it reactes.

Comment: Please share your drawable images here. let me check them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty easy... there is an property on ImageView that tells android how to deal when it needs to scale the image:

android:scaleType

so setting it properly i've

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/leftThumb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_left_thumb"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rightThumb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_right_thumb" />
```

In this way, instead of fitting the icon at the center of the spaceholder, it's is going to adjust to the edges

[image]